# Non-greedy jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to build jQuery selector to match html elements with the class "widget" in a "non-greedy" manner and without any document structure assumption. I mean: without matching inner subelements with the same class and not caring about if widget elements are direct sons or not.

The only way I know is also using .not() selector like:

```
$(".widget").not(".widget .widget");
```

But this way the selector is not able to find again "subwidgets" inside widget content.

For example, given this html:

```
<div class="otherClass">
    <h1>Some title</h1>
    <p>Some text...</h1>
    <div class="widget" id="w100">
        <div>
            <h2>Some intermediate level...</h2>
            <div class="widget" id="w110">
                <h2>Some title</h2>
                <div class="widget" id="w111">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="widget" id="w112">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="widget" id="w120">
            <h2>Some title</h2>
            <div class="widget" id="w121">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="widget" id="w122">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Assuming that the selector I'm trying to build is stored in a *selector* variable, I would like that:

```
var s0 = $(selector); // Matches div#w100 but not inner elements with "widget" class".
var s1 = $(selector, s0); // Matches div#w110 and div#w120
var s21 = $(selector, s1[0]); // Matches div#w111 and div#112
var s22 = $(selector, s1[1]); // Matches div#w121 and div#122
```

My goal is to implement a simple nestable widget system based on small controllers applyed to elements having the "widget" clas
s and other parameters in data-xxx attributes to pick the actual widget controller and parameters. But then, widgets must be ab
le to spread out other subwidgets in its html content.

Comment: You can use the parent element with the descendant selector to select only the parent `.widget` elements: `.otherClass > .widget`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question somewhat differently from everyone else here.  It seems to me that what you want is to traverse the DOM from some point, searching for `.widget` but not recursing below any element with that class.  Thus if you do this:

```
var tops = $( /* some selector here*/ );
```

you want the top-level widgets, and if you did this:

```
var next = $(tops[0]).find( /* some selector here*/ );
```

you want the 2nd-level widgets underneath the first top-level one, etc.

There is a plugin that does this:

https://github.com/jstnjns/jquery-nearest

I'll take the liberty of posting its code here:

```
(function() {

  $.fn.nearest = function(selector) {
    var $found = $(),
        checkChildren = function(filter) {
          var $children = this.children()
              $collection = $();

          $children.each(function() {
            var $matches = $(this).filter(filter),
                $fails = $(this).not(filter);

            if($matches.length) { $found = $found.add($matches); }

            if($fails.length) { checkChildren.call($fails, filter); }
          });
        };

    checkChildren.call(this, selector);

    return $found;
  }

}());
```

You would use this like so:

```
var tops = $(document).nearest(".widget");
var next = $(tops[0]).nearest(".widget");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I would mean! Now I'm online just with a smartphone so I cannot test it immediately. But, I think this is exactly what I were searching for.

Comment: So sorry for the delay. I tested it long time ago without success. I planned to test and analyze it deeply again, but I didn't until now. And I see it works perfectly. I probably commited some mistake in first test. Thank-you again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(".otherClass > .widget")`.

`>` stands for "First-level children".

Answer (score 0):

On second thought May be consider this a solution

https://jsfiddle.net/xejtj9gw/

which basically defines a function

```
function $Flevel(selector,parent)
{
    var sol=$(parent).children(selector);
   return sol;  
}
```

to access first level Children.

so the selectors need to be

```
var selector='div.widget';
var s0 = $Flevel(selector,'.otherClass');
var s1 = $Flevel(selector, s0); 
var s21 = $Flevel(selector, s1[0]); 
var s22 = $Flevel(selector, s1[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use immediate child selector:

```
$(".otherClass > .widget")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.otherClass').children('.widget')` since [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only matches first level.

This should be slightly faster than bare css selectors like `.otherClass > .widget`.

Comment: True. But I forgiven to say that I cannot assume they will be direct children. Only children with the widget class and without any other intermediate children with the same class. (I just edited my post to also say that). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use direct descendent selector **or** jQuery `children()` if you want to restrict in the way you described.  jQuery context selector by default acts the same as `find()` which will get all matching sub-elements:

[api.jquery.com docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $( "span", this ) is equivalent to $( this ).find( "span" ).

So to use indexes of a set you either need to do something like:

```
selector = '.otherClass > .widget';
var s0 = $(selector);
var s1 = $(s0).children('.widget');
var s22 = $(s1[0]).children('.widget');
```

or combine direct descendent with `nth-child()` object:

```
var selector = {};
selector.s0 = '.otherClass > .widget';
selector.s1 = selector + ' > .widget';
selector.s22 = s1 + ':nth-child(0) > .widget';

var s22 = $(selector.s22);
```

I'd probably be using selectors like the former.  Here's a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/udev4gzv/6/

```js
selector = '.otherClass > .widget';

var s0 = $(selector); // Matches div#w100 but not inner elements with "widget" class".
var s1 = $(s0).children('.widget'); // Matches div#w110 and div#w120
var s21 = $(s1[0]).children('.widget'); // Matches div#w111 and div#112
var s22 = $(s1[1]).children('.widget'); // Matches div#w121 and div#122

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#s0').html('s0 matches: ' + s0.map(function() { return this.id; }).get());
    $('#s1').html('s1 matches: ' + s1.map(function() { return this.id; }).get());
    $('#s21').html('s21 matches: ' + s21.map(function() { return this.id; }).get());
    $('#s22').html('s22 matches: ' + s22.map(function() { return this.id; }).get());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="otherClass">
    <h1>Some title</h1>
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <div class="widget" id="w100">
        <div class="widget" id="w110">
            <h2>Some title</h2>
            <div class="widget" id="w111">
               ...
            </div>
            <div class="widget" id="w112">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="widget" id="w120">
            <h2>Some title</h2>
            <div class="widget" id="w121">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="widget" id="w122">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<h3>results:</h3>
<div id="s0"></div>
<div id="s1"></div>
<div id="s21"></div>
<div id="s22"></div>
```